# Alternatives to the AisleFinder Supermarket API

Tags: android, ios, web-services, api

Are there any alternatives to the Supermarket API from AisleFinder? I've been using it in a mobile application, and determined that it's not really sufficient for my requirements. It contains aisle information for each product, but this information is almost never correct, and it returns too many unrelated items to each search.

I'm looking for alternative sources that contain (hopefully) aisle information and have items arranged in a hierarchy. For example, I want a search for '*fruit*' to mean actual **fruit**, possibly **apples** or **oranges**, not '*Gerber Graduates Purified Water Fruit Splashers*'.

Answer (score 3):

Im Curtiss, the Founder of AisleFinder. Sorry to hear that we dont fit your needs, but maybe our friends can: The ones that I like are [Scandit](http://www.scandit.com),Pushpins,[Scan.me](http://www.Scan.me),Greg London also has a dataset that might be to your liking as well.

On The other hand you are looking for "categories" , instead of individual products, and that might be your first problem.

Very few providers of this data actually allow "Full" category data dumps of categories (you wouldnt need them if you did )

Comment: Curtiss, wow. Definitely was not expecting that or the incredibly informative reply. So first, let me say that the entire reason I was drawn to the Supermarket API is the aisle locations. I can't say that I think it's the API's fault if the aisle information isn't accurate. Am I correct in assuming that much of this information comes directly from the stores themselves? That being said I would very much like to find out if there is a way of improving the results I do get. If you are amenable, I would like to open a new thread with an example query and the response.